# I am trying to use inputSwitch component of price faces but i am getting an error

Tags: primefaces

the error is -- "p:inputSwitch  Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: inputSwitch

Comment: Primefaces InputSwitch component is available for Elite-Pro users starting with 5.0.4 and with 5.1 for Community users. What Primefaces version do you use ? Make sure its over 5.0.4.

Check on http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3229 and http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputSwitch.xhtml

Comment: mine is 5.1 and the problem is when i am using when i am using inputSwitch inside a tabview then its not visible but when m using it in a different blank .xhtml page its working fine

Comment: and one more question regarding datatable...i have used editable datatable and its working fine apart from the fact that the changes made in the datatable for not reflected in the database(and m using Arraylist to retrieve values from database and then using it in the datatable)..please help

Answer (score 3):

InputSwitch was'nt invented before 5.1, so you are probably below that